# Multilevel list menu with JSON and jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I try to reach following structure

a list of (distinct!) categories

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category n

And each Category links to the posts within the Category. And the posts link to the content

- Post 1 Cat 1 --> Content Post 1 Cat 1
- Post 2 Cat 2 --> Content Post 2 Cat 1

**Question:** I don't know how to create the distinct list of categories which leads to the posts. Any solutions?

This is my JSON example (this is from the json api plugin in wordpress)

```
{"status": "ok",
"count": 10,
"count_total": 20,
"pages": 2,
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 86,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "inaktiviert",
        "url": "http://localhost/wordpress/?p=86",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Post 1 Cat1",
        "content": "his is content for Post1 Cat 1.",
        "date": "2014-03-04 15:09:51",
        "modified": "2014-03-04 15:09:51",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Category 1",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "post_count": 4
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": 84,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "kann-nicht-aktualisiert-werden",
        "url": "http://localhost/wordpress/?p=84",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Post 2 Cat1",
        "content": "<p>This is content for Post2 Cat 1.</p>\n",
        "date": "2014-03-04 15:09:25",
        "modified": "2014-03-04 15:09:25",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Category 1",
                "description": "",
                "parent": 0,
                "post_count": 4
            }
        ],
    },
        {
            "id": 74,
            "type": "post",
            "slug": "dieses-symbol-zeigt-an",
            "url": "http://localhost/wordpress/?p=74",
            "status": "publish",
            "title": "Post 1 Cat2",
            "content": "This is Content for Post1 Cat 2",
            "date": "2014-03-04 15:06:47",
            "modified": "2014-03-04 15:06:47",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "Category 2",
                    "description": "",
                    "parent": 0,
                    "post_count": 3
                }
            ],
        }
    ]}
```

And this my JS

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    var liste = $('#liste');

    var AllListItems = '';
    var AllDynamicPages = '';
    $.each(daten.posts, function(index1, data) {
        var postid = data.id;
        var postTitle = data.title;
        var postContent = data.content;

        for (var i = 0; i< data.categories.length; i++) {

            var catid = data.categories[i].id;     
            var catTitle = data.categories[i].title;            
            AllListItems += '<li><a href="#page' + postid + '">' + postTitle + '</a></li>';    
            AllDynamicPages += '<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="page' + postid + '"><div data-role="header"><h1>' + postTitle + '</h1></div><div data-role="content">' + postContent + '</div></div>'
        }        
    });

    liste.empty().append(AllListItems).listview("refresh");
    $("body").append(AllDynamicPages);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mariellel/7QTV9/2/)

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: Your JSON is not correct. Run it against [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @SandeepNayak sorry, updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it this way:  Instead of a list, create a collapsible set where each child collapsible is a category, and each category collapsible contains a list of posts.

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7QTV9/3/)**

So the top level HTML markup would be a collapsible set:

```
<div id="thelist" data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">       
</div>
```

Then the code:

```
var liste = $('#thelist');
var AllDynamicPages = '';
$.each(daten.posts, function(index1, data) {
    var postid = data.id;
    var postTitle = data.title;
    var postContent = data.content;        
    for (var i = 0; i< data.categories.length; i++) {
        var catid = data.categories[i].id;     
        var catTitle = data.categories[i].title;            
        //see if we already have this category, if not create new collapsible
        var $cat = $("#cat" + catid);
        if ($cat.length == 0){
            $cat = $('<div id="cat' + catid + '" data-role="collapsible"><h3>' + catTitle + '</h3><ul data-role="listview"></ul></div>');   
            liste.append($cat);
        }

        //create post link in category collapsible list
        var postlink = '<li><a href="#page' + postid + '">' + postTitle + '</a></li>';
        $cat.find("ul").append(postlink);

        AllDynamicPages += '<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="page' + postid + '"><div data-role="header"><h1>' + postTitle + '</h1></div><div data-role="content">' + postContent + '</div></div>'
    }        
});        
liste.enhanceWithin();
$("body").append(AllDynamicPages);
```

It is the same iteration as you had before, but now for each category, we check if there is already a collapsible for that category.  If there is not we create one and add it to the set.  Then we create a link for the post and add it the list widget within the category collapsible.

Finally we call `.enhanceWithin()` to apply jQM styling.

The dynamic pages part stays exactly the same.

Comment: For the external json: is it just

$.ajax({
url: 'http://www.example.org/?json=1',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',

});

at the end of the js?

Comment: $.getJSON or $.ajax, but you might run into cross-domain issues where you should look into JSONP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Comment: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/mariellel/7QTV9/4/) Is this the right way to include the JSON? Because I cant't see anything.

Comment: Use JSONP like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7QTV9/5/ Because it is an asynchronous call, the page will be blank for a second or two and then the data will load...

Comment: I have to thank you soooo much! :)
You really did a great job!